# repeat record in sql with respect to a column value

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm looking any logic to get the out of this data into given below format.

But am not able to find any logic to achieve this in sql.

Given Table

```
ID                   Country         AreaDiscount        Email  
AB0215000001         Belgium         120 cm + 10%        Abc@gmail.com
                                     130 cm + 20%        Abc@gmail.com
                                     140 cm + 30%        Abc@gmail.com
AB0215000002         Spain           220 cm + 30%        Bcd@gmail.com
                                     1420 cm + 30%       Bcd@gmail.com
                                     1520 cm + 10%       Bcd@gmail.com
```

Required

```
ID                   Country         AreaDiscount
AB0215000001         Belgium         120 cm + 10%
AB0215000001         Belgium         130 cm + 20%
AB0215000001         Belgium         140 cm + 30%                                                
AB0215000002         Spain           220 cm + 30%
AB0215000002         Spain           1420 cm + 30%
AB0215000002         Spain           1520 cm + 10%
```

Can I get any logic or suggestion to achieve this ?

Thanks !! :)

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Do you have a column that represents the ordering?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, No gordon !! I have mentioned the exact same data I have....

Comment: Is the given table already in the database? Are there further columns? What is the primary key?

Comment: @Recoil, Yes its a table in database. But no keys defined. Any idea recoil on this logic ?

Comment: Probably Gordon Linoff's answer is the best one under these circumstances. You need a parameter which ensures which entry relies to each other. The DB will not  guarantee that the eg. the 2nd row belongs to the first row. Maybe it belongs to row 4? Can you see the problem?

Comment: @Recoil, I got your point and also your and Gordon  words enlightened me that to accomplish this logic this data needs some reference where logic can be applied. But do you mind if I ask, What would be your approach if you'd allow to add any custom column  to apply logic ?

Comment: @Kate, I hope I've understand your question. I would export the Data into a Spreadsheet, search for a person who ist responsible for the data, let her/him correct/complete the datasets so that they are consistently and reimport the data into the table after a truncate. Maybe normalizing the structure, too ;) (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fully agreed with Gordon Linoff.

You can try following approach, which is a little bit different than his answer :

```
SELECT NVL(ID, NVL(LAG(ID IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY ROWID), ID)) AS ID,
       NVL(COUNTRY, NVL(LAG(COUNTRY IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY ROWID), COUNTRY)) AS COUNTRY,
       AREADISCOUNT
FROM   TAB1 T
ORDER  BY ROWID;
```

But be careful. The use of the rowid for this matter ist not really "best practice" and you have to check the result in detail for correctness!

**Update**

With the additional column, you may this for grouping/ordering:

```
SELECT NVL(ID, NVL(LAG(ID IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY EMAIL), ID)) AS ID,
       NVL(COUNTRY, NVL(LAG(COUNTRY IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY EMAIL), COUNTRY)) AS COUNTRY,
       AREADISCOUNT,
       EMAIL
FROM   TAB1 T
ORDER  BY ID, AREADISCOUNT;
```

Comment: As @Recoil points out, this is not a proper use of `rowid`.  The Oracle documentation doesn't even have a pretense that `rowid` in any way reflects insert order (because it doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a column that specifies the ordering, you can use `lag(. . . ignore nulls)`:

```
select lag(id ignore nulls) over (order by orderingcol) as id,
       lag(country ignore nulls) over (order by orderingcol) as country,
       areadiscount
from t;
```

Comment: You mean If I create any rounum column group by ID, could this help me to achieve this ? is this ordering you are talking about ?

Comment: @Kate . . . Yes.  SQL tables have no intrinsic ordering, so your rows can be in any order.  That makes it impossible to do what you want -- unless another column specifies the ordering.

Comment: I have updated the question. Now I've have one more column in dataset. Please check now ....There is now email id column.